# what is the difference between something and `something` in the linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to find all the .pdf files recursively by using find

So I typed in `find . -name *.pdf`

And the output was weird ,it only contains all the pdf files in the current directory , **other pdf fils in the sub directory is omitted**

Then I tried this `find . -name '*.pdf'`

This time ,every thing is fine .And I got what I want, I mean all the pdf files including those located in the sub directory.

So here comes the deal: what is the difference between `find . -name *.pdf` and `find . -name '*.pdf'`

Comment: *.pdf Search for all pdf file with any name. '*.pdf' It will search for the exact name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as you've found that quoting makes all the difference there.

Without quoting `*.pdf` gets expanded by shell glob expansion rule **even before find runs** and thus find command shows all the pdf files from that list only.

In other words this find command:

```
find . -name *.pdf
```

is same as:

```
printf "%s\n" *.pdf
```

So right way to use find is:

```
find . -name '*.pdf'
```

Comment: So `find . -name *.pdf` is expanded and you are in fact doing `find . -name file1.pdf file2.pdf` etc

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux shell (bash, csh, sh, and probably many others I'm not as familiar with), different quotes mean different things.

Fundamentally, quotes do two things for you:

1. **Limiting text substitution**: You're experiencing the shell substituting references to all PDF files in your current directory for `*.pdf`. That's an example of text substitution. Text substitution can also occur with variable names--for example:

   ```
   bash$ MYVAR=test
   bash$ echo $MYVAR
   test
   bash$ echo '$MYVAR'
   $MYVAR
   ```

   will give you the output `test`, because `$MYVAR` is substituted with the value the variable is set to.
2. **Overriding space as an argument separator**: Let's pretend you have a directory with these files

   ```
   bash$ ls -1
   file1
   file1 file2
   file2
   ```

   If you type `ls file1`, you'd get `file1` as you expect. Similarly, `ls file2` gives you `file2`. The following commands show the significance of quotes overriding space as an argument separator:

   ```
   bash$ ls -1 file1 file2
   file1
   file2
   bash$ ls -1 "file1 file2"
   file1 file2
   ```

   Notice how the first example displays two files `file1` and `file2`, while the second example displays one file `file1 file2`. That's because the quotes stop `" "` (a single space) from being used as an argument separator.

One final note: your original question asks about the difference between `something` and `'something'`. It's worth nothing that there is actually a difference between `something`, `'something'`, and `"something"`. Consider this:

```
bash$ MYVAR=test
bash$ echo $MYVAR
test
bash$ echo '$MYVAR'
$MYVAR
bash$ echo "$MYVAR"
test
```

Note the difference between `'$MYVAR'` and `"$MYVAR"`. The `'` (single quote) is considered a "strong quote," meaning everything contained inside it is explicit. The `"` (double quote) is a "weak quote," which does not expand `*` or `?`, but does expand variable names and command substitutions.

The [Grymorie](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html) provides a tremendous amount of information about quotes. Have fun learning!